How to slow down animation in "Loading" View?
Here is my code. The problem I have is that sometimes it runs very fast. Here is an example. What's wrong with my code?
public struct CircleLoadingView: View {
    @State private var isAnimating = false
    
    public init() {
    }

    public var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .trim(from: 0, to: 0.25)
            .stroke(Color.s500, lineWidth: 4)
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: isAnimating ? 360 : 0))
            .onAppear {
                withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                    isAnimating = true
                }
            }
            .onDisappear {
                isAnimating = false
            }
    }
}

struct CircleProgressViewDemo: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            CircleLoadingView()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}



The picture is blank.

I cannot reproduce on iOS 17.4.

it happens only on iOS15, sorry that I didn't make that clear
